# Link Target in iPhone Based web app

Tags: iphone, web

I am building a web application that is to be run by adding the app to the home screen.  Currently it has a list of users, clicking on a user takes you to a detail screen for that user and on that screen is a notes link to take the user to another screen with a grid of notes and a text box to add more notes.

When any links are clicked/tapped, the link is opened in Safari, not the current full screen Safari instance.  I tried setting the target of the link to _self, but this had no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned a full screen iPhone webapp can only be a single web page. Any link you try to open will launch Safari instead of replacing the current page.  To combat this, I used asp.net postbacks with panels to hide/load/show requested data.

Answer (score 0):

I use `target="_webapp"` and it works just use for example `<a href="http://your.link" target="_webapp">` and it gonna open the link without exit landscape (full screen) i dont know why but with some of my webapps works and sometimes dont.